# Data level Authorization in REST

Tags: sql, rest, authorization, role-base-authorization

I have Project(id, name, userId) table and Activity table (id, title, description, project_id). project_id is Foreign Key pointing to id in Project table. Project data can be accessed only by the user who created it.

Now, I have REST Api exposed to create new activity for particular project :

Method: POST

Body {
"title" : "Test activity",
"description" : "Test description",
"project_id" : "123"

}

It is consumed by web application. However, of course it can be consumed external REST clients as well.

Problem:
A user who hasn't created "project P" can add activity to "project P" by giving the "project P"'s id in above Rest call. I want to prevent this from happening. I can certainly write validation logic by fetching the project data from given project Id and checking if current user owns the project but I want more generic solution.
Also, please note that this is insert only problem.
Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

Try writing logic to fetch projects that a user owns, then validating if the current user is accessing their own project.

Comment: "I can certainly write validation logic by fetching the project data from given project Id and checking if current user owns the project but I want more generic solution. "

Comment: not from the given project id, but from the current user. what you were saying is you use the given project id to find out the project creator then compare if the creator is the current user. this limits your validation is project based, but really your validation should be user based, so im suggesting to use the current user find out the resources that current user owns, assuming you have authentication for your REST API

Comment: Got you. I updated the project table definition to have "userId" as foreign key. Thus, from project Id I can find who is the owner. But Anyway, I don't want to repeat this in every REST call I write. I am looking for generic one.